# Can't create an sql server on azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to do the following tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started/

When I try to create the SQL server, after I set the name and passwords and those things, and azure begins to create the server, it gives me two errors:

[image]

I'm in free tier of dreamspark if that information is useful. Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure SQL is not included in the free tier of dreamspark.

The error is probably due to being locked in the free tier, will have to add a credit card and pay to use Azure SQL.

You can, however, get a free MySQL database through ClearDB and Azure. For more info, see this page: https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=99